Watchnet NVR Configuration with VLAN
I have Watchnet NVR with POE Camera. My network is configured with 3 LAN segments. How can I configure my NVR? Some camera's are connected on POE Switch. But these camera's are not coming on the NVR. How can I configure these IP camera's with VLAN?
To make it clear We have:-

One Core switch
Four Access switch which are manageable Except one of them.
Please help me!


Sorry, applications and host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. Usually, end nodes are connected to an 'access' port with a single, untagged VLAN. Additionally, VLANs require a managed switch.
